# Pesquisa - Mostrar Mensagem caso os resultados não forem encontrados

Tags: javascript, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou com um probleminha no javascript, peguei um js que faz o search na tabela, porém quando não há registros ele apenas não mostra nada, como faço para colocar um "return" com alguma frase quando não houver registros,tentei algumas vezes mas sem sucesso. Segue:

```
// Write on keyup event of keyword input element
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    _this = this;
    // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
    $.each($("#table tbody").find("tr"), function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) == -1)
            $(this).hide();
        else
            $(this).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Onde você quer mostrar essa frase? No lugar da tabela?

Comment: Isso, defini a tag tfoot lá no html com um id, e agora quando não mostrar resultado nenhum (que não foi encontrado), dar um append lá na tfoot

Comment: Dê uma olhada na minha resposta. =)

Answer (score 1):

Tudo que você vai precisar fazer é identificar quanto todas as `tr` estiverem com `display:none` e quando estiverem mostrar a mensagem informando que não existe dados para o filtro informado.

**Exemplo:**

JS:

```
var table = $("#table tbody").find("tr");
var mensagem = $("#mensagem");
mensagem.hide();
$("#search").keyup(function() {
  _this = this;
  $.each(table, function() {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) == -1)
      $(this).hide();
    else
      $(this).show();
  });

  var tableDisplay = table.css('display');

  mensagem.hide();
  if (tableDisplay === 'none') {
    mensagem.show();
  }

});
```

HTML:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="search">
  </div>
</form>

<table class="table table-hover" id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Gabriel</td>
    <td>Rodrigues</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Highlander</td>
    <td>Imortal</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="mensagem">Sem resultados</div>
```

Fora do `each()` coloquei uma variavel para mostrar o display das `tr`, quando todas estiverem ocultas ele irá entrar na  condição  que mostrará a mensagem.

Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5vfgk0y5/4/)

Comment: Obrigado pela disposição em ajudar, eu estava querendo trocar o alert por um append diretamente na tfoot, algo semelhante a isso:

var table = $("#table tbody").find("tr");

$("#search").keyup(function() {
  _this = this;

  $.each(table, function() {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) == -1)
      $(this).hide();
    else
      $(this).show();
  });

  var tableDisplay = table.css('display');

  if (tableDisplay === 'none') {
      $("#paragrafosAdicionais").append("<tr>" +
        "<td colspan="3">Sem resultados</td>" +
        "</tr>");
  }

});

Comment: Em vez de trabalhar com o tfoot que vai requerir css por que ficará mal formatada com as td coloque uma div no final e deixe ela com a mensagem, vou editar com exemplo

Comment: Agora sim deu certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda rss

Comment: @RafaelRibeiro Se minha resposta resolveu o seu problema marque ela como aceita ;)

Comment: Esse funcionou "corretamente", desculpa a demora mas nesse javascript até quando acha um registro ele tende a apresentar que não foram encontrados resultados.

Answer (score 1):

Adicionei ID no tfoot e criei uma flag que recebe a quantidade de registros da tabela e subtrai toda vez que oculta um item, se ao final o valor da flag for 0 eu mostro a mensagem.

```
var table = $("#table tbody").find("tr");

$("#search").keyup(function() {
  _this = this;
  flag = table.length;

  $.each(table, function() {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) == -1) {
      $(this).hide();
      flag--;
    } else {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });

  if (!(flag > 0))
    $("#retorno").html("Não foram encontrados resultados");
  else
    $("#retorno").html("");
});
```

**Exemplo funcional:** https://jsfiddle.net/scs5jo2e/

Comment: Qualquer semelhança com a minha resposta e mera coincidência, detalhe testa ai que não esta funcionando direito com 1 registro encontrado.

Comment: Sim, eu usei seu fiddle como base e obrigado pelo alerta, corrigi! =)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela disposição galera, me ajudou muito, de verdade.

Answer (score 0):

Veja se isso vai dar certo:

```
<div id="msg"></div>
```

.....

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    _this = this;
    // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
    $.each($("#table tbody").find("tr"), function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) == -1)
            $(this).hide();
            $("#msg").html("<span class="alert-warning">Ops, nada foi encontrado</span>");
        else
            $(this).show();
            $("#msg").html("<span class="alert-success">Opa, encontramos alguma coisa</span>");
    });
});
```

Comment: É exatamente isso que eu quero fazer mas ao invés de acrescentar na div colocar no tfoot, esse código não funcionou.

Comment: E assim, no lugar do 
$("#msg").html("<span class="alert-warning">Ops, nada foi encontrado</span>");

Vc usar isso:
$("#table tfoot").find("td").html("blablabla");

Ou ainda assim:
<tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="msg"></span></td>

    </tr>
  </tfoot>
Ai usando a dica da resposta de ontem